# How do I manage version control when developing with SQL Server Express?

Tags: database, version-control, ddl, sql-server-2005-express

I am developing a website using SQL Server Express on my development machine. My web hosting company is providing me with SQL Server 2005.

At the moment all I have is a database that I develop with and a database that is on the live server. I do not have the original scripts to generate the schema but I can auto generate the create scripts individually or for the entire database.

I am now putting my code into source control and I would like to know how I manage my database schema. What do I put into it? Create commands? Alter scripts?

The database is very small at the moment and it is not hard to maintain the two databases, but I am concerned that going forward but it will get out of hand. Do you have any tips for getting the live database in sync when deploying new code?

**EDIT** Any ideas as to what should go into source control? Should the DDL scripts go here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deploy schema changes as DDL upgrade scripts and, if you haven't already, add a table to contain the schema version number which you update at the end of each upgrade script.

EDIT: Yes, all your scripts should go into source control, including DDL scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I typically keep a testing copy of the live database on my local or virtual development box, which I flush routinely from the prod database down to testing.  The testing copy is meant for my total exploitation.  When I have something that I believe is ready for deployment, I move it to my development dataset, which mirrors the prod db and is not used for playing around.  If the development db passes all my tests, I deploy the script to the production db